# Install preconfigured Debian or Ubuntu on KVM VPS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, vps, preseed

I'd like to install a preconfigured Debian or Ubuntu on my KVM VPS.

My VPS provides the option to boot from a custom iso image. In the past I uploaded the official iso and did all the setup process by myself which also meant to open up a VNC connection till I can connect with SSH.

I read about a preseed.cfg you have to pack inside the .iso that would do that job. But actually you have to do a lot of steps (download, mount, set permissions, extract multiple layers, add preseed.cfg, pack again, add md5 hashes) to do so but it seems to me like a very common task which requires only two parameters. The official .iso and the preseed.cfg to make a new .iso. Am I missing something? Is there any easier solution?

Thanks.